# How to join 2 tables in JPQL?

Tags: sql, jpql

I have a SQL query that works correctly

```
SELECT ref_model_id,
       COUNT(*) AS total_assets,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE ref_asset_id IS NOT NULL) AS reserved_asset,
       COUNT(*) - COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE ref_asset_id IS NOT NULL)
FROM am_asset aa
         LEFT JOIN am_asset_reservation aar ON aar.ref_asset_id = aa.id AND is_active = TRUE
WHERE status = 'in_stock'
GROUP BY ref_model_id
```

I tried to bring it to JPQL and this is what happened:

```
<query>
    <![CDATA[select e.refModel, count(*), count(*) filter (where a.refAsset is not null),
        count(*) - count(*) filter (where a.refAsset is not null)
        from am_Asset e
        left join am_AssetReservation a on a.refAsset = e.refModel and a.isActive = TRUE
        WHERE e.status = 'in_stock'
        GROUP BY e.refModel]]>
</query>
```

Unfortunately, query doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

The result should be a table consisting of 4 columnns:

1. the name of the model
2. total number of models
3. booked number of models
4. free balance

Answer (score 0):

You may try something along the lines of the following:

```
SELECT
    aa.ref_model_id,
    COUNT(aa) AS total_assets,
    SUM(CASE WHEN aar.ref_asset_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS reserved_asset,
    COUNT(aa) - SUM(CASE WHEN aar.ref_asset_id IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
FROM AmAsset aa
LEFT JOIN aa.AmAssetReservation aar
WHERE status = 'in_stock'
GROUP BY aa.ref_model_id
```

Instead of the ugly `SUM(CASE WHEN ...)` you *might* be able to just use `COUNT(aar.ref_asset_id)`.